# How to print the exact result of a command to a file

Tags: terminal, zsh, printing, echo, printf

## Context

I have a file `my-cmd`:

```bsh
echo '<some data...>\\<some other data...>'
```

Basically, I want to redirect the output of this command to a text file:

```bsh
./my-cmd > file.txt
```

## Question

My problem is that `>` always replaces any occurrence of `\\` to `\` in `file.txt`.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Why do you need `echo "$( ... )"` at all? why can't you redirect the output directly `my-cmd > file.txt`?

Comment: @steeldriver You got a point, I simplified my question. However, I still have the issue of \\ transformed into \ when redirected with `>`

Comment: How does `my-cmd` produce its output?

Comment: @NickD Does it matter? Currently it `echo '<data>'`'s it (with single quotes).

Comment: Very related: [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is a non-portable command whose behaviour varies across implementations, versions, their compile-time and runtime option and the environment.

In particular, you shouldn't use it if its first argument may start with `-` (though zsh's builtin `echo` is one of the rare implementations that can work around that) or if any argument contains backslash characters.

Specifically with the `zsh` `echo` builtin implementation, `\` sequences (like `\n`, `\c`, `\61`, `\\`...) are expanded (as required by POSIX+XSI, while POSIX without XSI leaves the behaviour unspecified) unless the `bsdecho` option is enabled (disabled by default on most deployments), while for `bash` they are only expanded when the `xpg_echo` is enabled (disabled by default on most deployments).

Both `zsh` and `bash` `echo`s support a (non-standard) `-E` option to disable  the expansions (not supported by `bash`'s if both the `xpg_echo` and `posix` options are enabled though).

Here, even though you could do:

```
echo -E '<some data...>\\<some other data...>' > file
```

Which would work OK in `zsh` and in most deployments of `bash`, it would be much better to use the standard `printf` command:

```
printf '%s\n' '<some data...>\\<some other data...>' > file
```

Whose behaviour in that case is completely specified by POSIX and works the same across all implementations.

Note that the `printf` utility is a POSIX invention. Long before POSIX, the Korn shell's answer to that non-portable `echo` mess-up was a new `print` builtin and its `-r` option to not expand `\x` sequences and a `-` to mark the end of options. `zsh` does have a Korn-like `print` builtin, but `bash` doesn't.

In ksh and zsh, you can also do:

```
print -r - "$var"
```

To print arbitrary data as-is.

More details at:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: Where did you learn all of this? 0_0

Answer (score 3):

If `my-cmd` does something like this:

```
echo "abc\\def"
```

the output will be `abc\def`: the backslash is interpreted as an escape character inside double quotes. OTOH, it is treated as a literal backslash inside single quotes:

```
echo 'abc\\def'
```

will produce `abc\\def` as output.

EDIT: This was tested with bash. The OP has since changed the tag to "zsh", so this does not answer his question. If the moderators think it's now irrelevant, I  will delete it.

Comment: When sent to a text file: `echo 'abc\\def' > file.txt`, then `file.txt` is fed with `abc\def`

Comment: Not here: `$ echo 'abc\\def' > foo.txt`, `$cat foo.txt` output:
`abc\\def`

Comment: Well, I just tried it right now, and I cannot come to the same conclusion as you. Thought I'm using zsh: does zsh treat differently `>`?

Comment: @Louis-JacobLebel You're not using `/bin/echo`, but `zsh`'s built-in `echo` with enabled escape sequences. Use `echo -E '…'` to disable the interpretation of escape sequences. It has nothing to do with redirection.

Comment: @Freddy That was it. Actually under zsh, `echo -E '...'` prints `-E ...`... but `/bin/echo -E '...'` works like magic!

Comment: @Louis-JacobLebel Are you sure you're using `zsh`? What's the output of `echo $0`?

Comment: @Louis-JacobLebel _Please_ tag you question with the *correct shell*. It is current tagged with [tag:bash].  The `echo` in [tag:zsh] is likely to have its own quirks. Also, please make it clear in the question how your command actually produces its output. Yes, this matters a lot.  If these things are left in comments or can't be determined by reading the actual question, the question will be closed as "unclear".

Comment: @Kusalananda You are right, I forgot that zsh and bash were two different things. I changed the `bash` tag to `zsh`. Adding how `my-cmd` prints data to the question too.

Comment: @Freddy `echo $0` returns `zsh`, so I must be under `zsh` shell

Answer (score 0):

According to [what Freddy said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545421/how-to-print-the-exact-result-of-a-command-to-a-file#comment1011738_545428) in the comments of [NickD's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545428/351141), `my-cmd` should be:

```bsh
/bin/echo -E '<some data...>\\<some other data...>'
```

So basically, because I'm under `zsh` and *not* `bash`, by default I'm using an `echo` command that treats backslash characters specially. I had to tell `zsh` that I want to use the `/bin/echo` command instead, and also had to call it with its `-E` option.

Here's what `man echo` says about the `-E` option:

> ```
>    -E     disable interpretation of backslash escapes
> ```

Comment: zsh's `echo` does support `-E` as well, no need for `/bin/echo` (which on many systems doesn't support `-E`). It also supports `print -r` like `ksh` and the POSIX `printf '%s\n' ...`. `bash` also expands `\\` sequences (as required by POSIX+XSI) when in compliance mode. The correct answer here is to **not** use `echo`, but `printf` instead.

Answer (score -1):

**Answer**

As you know, the `>` is a output redirector operatory (Essentially meaning it redirectrs the output of a command to a certain place)

If you want to redirect multiple outputs to the same file, then you should use the `>>` command. It uses the same syntax as the `>` command but instead of entirely re-writing / erasing the data your previously redirected, it will just add it below.

**Example / Syntax**

So instead of doing `./my-cmd > file.txt`, do `./my-cmd >> file.txt`

Comment: all that's true, but has nothing to do with double backslashes getting changed to single backslashes.